# How to place multiple images (with hover effect) next to each other in a row?

Tags: html, image, repeat

I am VERY amateur in html. I would like to place three images (with an image over image hover effect) next to each other. I currently have the following code that I am using to display an image with the hover effect, however when I copy and paste this for the second or third image (with the new image url) it still shows the first images/hovers for all consecutive placements. I assume that it has something to do with the "background" but I'm not sure. Any idea how I can place/repeat three different images (with an image over image hover effect) next to each other?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .imgBox {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background: url(https://www.thefoodful.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/learn-e1505840114120.jpg) no-repeat;
        }

        .imgBox:hover {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background: url(https://www.thefoodful.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/learn-2-e1505840096664.jpg) no-repeat;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="imgBox"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try associate each image with different "id"

Comment: How exactly would I do that? I'm changing the "background url" for each image (and hover image) but it still shows the image of the first set of html coding I use.

Comment: keep updating your code i will guide you, but won't do it for as it will not help u!

Comment: I've figured out what an "image id" is and have finally updated the code to reflect what I wanted. BUT NOW I can't figure out how to make the image/hover a clickable link.

Here is the code, now:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
.imgsrc
{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background: url(https://www.thefoodful.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/learn-e1505840114120.jpg) no-repeat;
       
}

.imgsrc:hover {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background: url(https://www.thefoodful.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/learn-2-e1505840096664.jpg) no-repeat;
    
 }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="imgsrc">
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I know that I need to add THIS code in...I just don't know where. I've tried to add it in, in multiple places and can't get it to work. 

<a href="https://www.thefoodful.com/lhome/learn">
  <img src="MY IMAGE">
</a>

Comment: You are adding wrong source of the image!